# Is there an alternative .NET logging class to ILogger / EventLog that runs on Mac?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, blazor, apple-m1, asp.net-core-5.0

I am injecting an object in a Blazor app as a singleton that is constructed using ILogger;

```
public MessageBroker(ILogger<MessageBroker> logger, IOptions<MessageBrokerConfig> config)
```

The app (.NET Core 5.0) crashes when I navigate to that page with;

```
Exception":"System.PlatformNotSupportedException: EventLog access is not supported on this platform.
```

I guess logging is one of the trickier functions to make cross platform because it is directly to the OS.

Does anyone know of an alternative to ILogger that will work on Mac Silicon, Windows, and Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in `ILogger`, but in its configuration. Apparently, it uses `EventLog`, [which is used to write logs to Windows Event Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#welog), not available on other platforms.

You most likely have something like that in your logging configuration.

```cs
logging.AddEventLog()
```

If you don't need to use Windows Event Log, just remove this line and use [other logging providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#third-party-logging-providers) instead. [Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#console) is the most basic one, just writes your logs in standard output.

If you are looking for more advanced scenarios, like logging to files or external log collectors, I can recommend [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) or [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/), they should work on all platforms without an issue. You can find other alternatives in [awesome-dotnet-core](https://github.com/thangchung/awesome-dotnet-core/#logging) repo

---

If you really need to use Windows Event Log (e.g., your production server is Windows, but you develop on MacOS machine), you should probably wrap this line in an `if` statement and control it with configuration parameter

```cs
if (context.Configuration["UseEventLog"] == "true")
{
    logging.AddEventLog()
}
```

Comment: Thank you @denis-palashevskii!
Someone else from the team added that configuration but I should have caught that. We don't need the event log (or deploy on Windows), so shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Necroing a bit, but if you use Default Builder, just call the ClearProviders() method and it will remove it all for you. Since I use the Trace class for my loggings I don't really care for the Hosting logging solution. :)